# Yii output duplicate contents

Tags: php, yii, render, renderpartial

Frontend guy talking about backend - bear in mind.

We have a module called `Ideas` which has some kind of timeline with different entries of ideas per project.

The initial render, at the `IdeasProjectController.php` goes through an `actionView` method to render a view to screen, but I wanted to re-use this action so I could request some sort of paginated content from this action method instead.

This is how it looks now:

```
$data = array(
    'user' => $user,
    'project' => $project,
    'ideas' => $ideas,
    'myIdeas' => false,
    'offset' => isset($offset) ? $offset : 0,
    'isAjaxRequest' => $isAjaxRequest,
    'isVotingActive' => $project->isVotingActive(),
    'userHasIdeas' => count($userIdeas) > 0,
    'teamInviteParams' => $teamInviteParams,
);

// renderPartial only if an ajax request
if ($isAjaxRequest) {
    $this->renderPartial('view', $data, null, true);
} else {
    $this->render('view', $data);
}
```

In the `view.php` file associated we use the `isAjaxRequest` param to finally trigger the rendering of a different twig file, with a similar set of data, knowing that the file requested by the full `render` contains the twig file I'm using for the `renderPartial`. In this way:

```
if( $isAjaxRequest ) {

    Yii::app()->twig->render('blocks/l-ideas/b-ideas-list/b-ideas-list.twig', array(..)

} else {

    Yii::app()->twig->render('blocks/l-ideas/l-ideas-project/l-ideas-project.twig', array(..)
```

All good so far. But I need `b-ideas-list` to be used at the layout twig file like this: `{% use '/blocks/l-ideas/b-ideas-list/b-ideas-list.twig' %}` with completely different results, so this is how `b-ideas-list.twig` looks like inside:

```
{% block bIdeasList %}

    {% if not isAjaxRequest %}
        <div class="b-ideas-list__wrap b-ideas-list__wrap_no-margin">
            .. lots of boilerplate ..
        </div>

        <div class="b-ideas-list b-ideas-list_covers clearfix">

            <div class="b-ideas-list__wrap">
                <div class="clearfix b-ideas-list__wraper-fixed-box">

                    <div class="b-ideas-list__left">&#160;</div>
                    <div class="b-ideas-list__center">
                        {{ block('bIdeasList_') }}
                        {{ block('bIdeasMore_') }}
                    </div>

                    {{ block('bIdeasListPartners_') }}

                </div>
                {{ block('bIdeasListActiveIdeas_') }}
            </div>

        </div>

    {% else %}
        {{ block('bIdeasList_') }}
        {{ block('bIdeasMore_') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This way, on an AJAX request, I just get the minimum list of ideas and a `More` button to load more on the next AJAX request. With some offset, etc.

Now. If I make a http access to the resulting URL, something like `/ideas/ideasProject/view/1?offset=5` having just 7 entries in the database, I get two new ideas, and the full layout. But making the same access through an AJAX call to the same URL, I'm getting the two ideas cards, stripped of layout, and THEN the boilerplate code surrounding the `bIdeasList` block as if I had not accessed with `isAjaxRequest` to true, in just one single call.

If you are still reading this. Do you think you can help?

Comment: I'm not sure If I understood, but if you want to remove the layout you could just use in your controller

if ($isAjaxRequest) {
   $this->layout = false;
}